# HowTo? CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How would I amend my calls to

```
sqlalchemy.func.current_timestamp()
```

with something that generates

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A quick fix would be to do the following:

```py
func.current_timestamp().op('AT TIME ZONE')('UTC')
```

A more proper way is to use [compiler](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/compiler.html) extension and define custom compilation of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Actually, there's already an [example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/compiler.html#utc-timestamp-function) in its docs, which uses a different approach (`TIMEZONE` function). Since you only need this for Postgres (I assume from your previous emails in SA mailing list that you're using Postgres), here's another (nicer) quick fix:

```py
func.timezone('UTC', func.current_timestamp())
```

Comment: I always forget how to do this. I was searching in Google for minutes before finding this.

All I'm saying is, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Neither of those work if the function is used in `server_default` in a `Column` definition; in that case the approach in the referenced example (now [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html#utc-timestamp-function)) does work.

Comment: What is func.timezone? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @genhernandez See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT