# How can I get the utc_date from timestamptz using sqlalchemy in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am selecting the utc_date from a timestamptz object using `(trade_dt at time zone 'utc')::date as utc_date'. I wish to replicate this using sqlalchemy.

from sqlalchemy import func, cast, Date

Comment: Answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424199/howto-current-timestamp-at-time-zone-utc